# Source not found Error in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I'm fairly new to Eclipse and I'm using Kepler with EGit right now but I ran into a problem every time I compile my Java application. I've searched this forum to find a solution for my problem but I am still very confused as to what I can do to fix it. The application worked flawlessly yesterday morning and it works fine on my project partner's laptop but after syncing the project with 4 new commits from my project partner today, I keep getting a Source not found error every time I try to run the application. I get a button saying Edit Source Lookup Path and when I click on it and expand the folders, I get something that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of my screen]

There are a bunch of .jar files above what you see and maTKProject is the name of my project.

If anyone could give some insight on how to fix this problem, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What source is it trying to find?

Comment: @SLaks Part of my problem is that I don't really understand what it is trying to find. All my java classes are contained in that src folder under my package name and I've tried clicking on all the different folders but all of them return the same error

Comment: What's the title of the tab saying Source not found?

Comment: Have you tried a Project -> clean?

Comment: @SLaks the tab says Class<T>.getDeclaredMethods0(boolean) line: not available [native method].

And I have just tried cleaning it and it didn't change much.

Comment: That's a native method.  It doesn't have any source.

Comment: Are you trying to run the application in debug mode? Go to Window -> Show View -> Breakpoints and make sure there aren't any that shouldn't be there!

Comment: @BarbiePylon Hahahah yes! That was the problem! I was messing around with Breakpoints because I didn't really know what it did and I guess I forgot to reset it after I was done playing with it! Thank you very very much!

Comment: @BarbiePylon, please wrap your comment as an answer and post it, so after acceptance this question can be closed, and others may learn from it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attaching Java Source to Android projects in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182904/attaching-java-source-to-android-projects-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the application in debug mode make sure that there aren't any breakpoints that shouldn't be there. Go to Window -> Show View -> Breakpoints and remove as necessary!